# Redirect to HTTPS using Google Cloud Load Balancer with two IP-s

Tags: redirect, load-balancing, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I’m trying to set up HTTPS with the help of Google load balancer. I created instance group, front ends,  backends, health checker and the actual load balancer. 
I set up two Frontends one for HTTP on port 80 and HTTPS on port 443.  They have different IP-s respectively.

I then pointed my DNS to the HTTPS (443) version of my IP.

It works great when I point my browser directly to https://example.com

However, when I use nonsecure protocol, I want to redirect the user to secure connection.  After some reading, I learned that the only way to do this is directly from my node.js app (or nginx). what I do is check if `req.headers['x-forwarded-proto']` is false and redirect to `'https://' + global.config.hostname + req.url`

`global.config.hostname` is set to `example.com`

```
primoz@static-server[master]$ wget http://example.com
--2017-08-30 10:13:12--  http://example.com/
Resolving example.com... 35.196.241.151
Connecting to example.com|35.196.241.151|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2017-08-30 10:13:12 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

35.196.241.151 is example of HTTPS  IP from my load balancer set up listening on port 443.

It looks to me that the redirect is trying to access my secure HTTPS IP over port 80 and it’s not accessible.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what I found out.

It's a common problem a lot of people have, take a look at this issue thread where people are requesting an easier way to set this up.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35904733

I fixed this by setting up static IP instead of the ephemeral IP for HTTP and HTTPS frontends. This way they both have the same IP and the redirect inside your node app or nginx works as it should.

Comment: How were you able to assign two front ends to the same ip address? Doesn't seem possible

Comment: @Rondo one with HTTP and the other one with HTTPS protocol. But first, you have to create new static IP in the External IP addresses section of GCP.

Comment: doesn't seem to reflect the realities of typical web architecture, does it? How would one setup DNS so that both ports are serviced by the same fqdn? Round robin DNS is not just non-ideal, it could just cause chaos is some cases.

Comment: You don't set up DNS to any port, it just points to static IP address. I have an HTTP to HTTPS redirect set up on the actual server with nginx.

Comment: I know how DNS works. let me put it this way: I need both port 80 and 443 on the same FQDN to be handled by one loadbalancer. You have to apparently setup two IP addresses on two separate services: one for each port. If that is not true, plz explain how that is done with one service.